# Separate current date from time on Android

Tags: android, datetime, timestamp

I am getting the current date from Google and it's giving me response like this:

```
date = **"Tue, 17 Mar 2020 12:37:44 GMT"**
```

But I only want the date so I am converting timeStamp, but I couldn't get the desired result.

I have this code in the onCreate() method:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet("https://google.com/"));
                    StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
                    if (statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                        String date = response.getFirstHeader("Date").getValue();
                        Log.d("Date : ", date);
                        System.out.println("d :" + date);
                       timeStamp = date;
                        getTime();
                    } else {
                        //Closes the connection.
                        response.getEntity().getContent().close();
                        throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
                    }
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    Log.d("Response", e.getMessage());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.d("Response", e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });

        thread.start();
```

After coming in getTime() method, the app didn't toast me the **result**. Here is the code:

```
private void getTime() {
        String timeStampST = timeStamp;
        SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        Date date = null;
        String resultDate = null;
        try {
            date = fmt.parse(timeStampST);
            SimpleDateFormat fmtOut = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd yyyy");
            resultDate = fmtOut.format(date);
            Toast.makeText(this, resultDate, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

**Note**: I want to get the date like this

**Date**: Tue, 17 Mar 2020

That's why I am converting the timeStamp, but it's not working.

Comment: Are you getting any exception or error message? Please paste into your question. Also, if the string from Google is in GMT (as in the example), do you want the date in GMT or in some other time zone?

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use java.time, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: I want to get the date from google 
It just give me nothing and close the program and if I toast something it crashes app that you can toast as you are not in UI thread

Comment: When I read your code, I am pretty convinced that an exception is thrown inside `getTime()` and caught in the `catch` block in the same method. If you don’t see the stack trace from `e.printStackTrace();`, you’ve got a serious flaw in your project setup that you need to fix first thing and before we can help you with that exception. As long as you cannot see the error messages from your program, you are coding blindfolded.

Comment: @OleV.V. if you are asking for  stack trace from e.printStackTrace();
its giving me the exception that ( unparseable date (at offset 0) )

Comment: I got the issue posting in answer

Comment: What does *"After coming in getTime() method, the app didn't toast me the result"* mean (please respond by [editing your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/15015952/edit), not here in comments, as appropriate)?

Comment: @PeterMortensen I have edited my answer and I hope you got your answer now please upvote the question it. I didn't get why you downvoted it?

Answer (score 0):

Above in my question, the approach I'm using was not correct in the **getTime** method so I what now I'm doing in getTime method is described below
Firstly, I get the timeStamp value. You can get it by writing **convert timestamp to date** on Google. Open the first link and get your timeStamp value.

In **getTime()** method, you just have to create a Calendar object and set your timestamp data on it. You will get the timestamp data into your calendar object and you can turn it to a string using **DateFormat.format**. Like this:

```
long timeStampValue = 1584517882L;
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
cal.setTimeInMillis(timeStampValue * 1000L);
String date = DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd", cal).toString();
Log.d("date: ", date);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 String arrDate[] = date.split(" ");
 String  newDate = arrDate[0]+" "+ arrDate[1] + " " + arrDate[2] +" "+arrDate[3];
```

If you receive every time same date format then you split the string using space and you will get array data. After you got array data you join array index as your requirement. This will be work fine but this not proper code for converting date.

Comment: Whats this and where should I use it?

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: If you receive every time same date format then you split the string using space and you will get array data.After you got array data you join array index as your requirement.This will be work fine but this not proper code for converting date.